# Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) spring boot application stops working without error

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot application that works fine locally.  Using Postman to send the JSON string and complete the request successfully.

I deploy the application to our development PCF environment.  The application that uses the service calls it successfully.  In the service logs, it correctly identifies the strategy to use and works fine.  Then it should call the DAO, but nothing happens.  No error, no logging statements that are in the DAO before any database operation is called.  It just stops.

There are 2 other applications that have been developed and deployed to use this service and they are working fine.  This is the area where the service stops working:

```
@Component
public class LoadStrategy implements CloseStrategy {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadStrategy.class);

    private LoadDao loadDao;
    private MapperTranslator<Map<String, Object>, CloseRequest> mapperTranslatorToInputStream;
    private MapperTranslator<CloseResponse, Map<String, Object>> mapperTranslatorToCloseTrailerResponse;

    @Autowired
    public Load Strategy(LoadDao loadDao, 
            @Qualifier("loadRequestMapper")MapperTranslator<Map<String, Object>, CloseRequest> mapperTranslatorToInputStream,
            @Qualifier("loadResponseMapper")MapperTranslator<CloseResponse, Map<String, Object>> mapperTranslatorToCloseResponse) {
        this.loadDao = loadDao;
        this.mapperTranslatorToInputStream = mapperTranslatorToInputStream;
        this.mapperTranslatorToCloseResponse = mapperTranslatorToCloseResponse;
    }

    public CloseResponse close(CloseRequest input) {
        LOGGER.info("Before call to loadDao");
        Map<String, Object> translator = mapperTranslatorToInputStream.translate(input);
        LOGGER.info("Completed input stream mapper. Before calling loadDao");
        Map<String, Object> result = loadDao.close(translator);
        return mapperTranslatorToCloseTrailerResponse.translate(result);
    }
}
```

The service prints the logger statement **"Completed input stream mapper. Before calling loadDao"** then nothing.
In the DAO there is a logger statement at the beginning of that method that is not printed.

THis is the DAO class..

```
@Repository
public class LoadDao implements CloseDao {

    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDao.class);

    @Autowired
    public LoadDao(@Qualifier("loadSummaryJdbcCall") SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall) {
        this.simpleJdbcCall = simpleJdbcCall;
    }

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "closeFallback")
    public Map<String, Object> close(Map<String, Object> input) {
        Map<String, Object> result;

        LOGGER.debug("In loadDao Before {}.{} Procedure. Input Stream: {}", PACKAGE, PROCEDURE, input.get(P_INPUT_STREAM));
```

...rest of class...

I don't know where to start troubleshooting this problem  This is my first application of Spring Boot and in the PCF environment.
Any areas that I can look into would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has this issue...
I changed the logging level to TRACE using 'CONFIGURE LOGGING LEVELS'. So I can see the output now.